# Why is Host Name in Google Analytics showing other websites along with my website?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-spam, mirror, plagiarism

In Google Analytics, `Audience -> Geo -> Location -> Secondary dimension: Host Name`, I see three different websites along with my website. When I checked those websites, I can see they have copied my code and mirrored my website. I see a similar design but with different content.

Why is Google Analytics showing those sites in my reports? What should I do now?

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing those domains cause they copied your analytics code. By default, you only need to include the tracking code to start sending data to Analytics platform (regardless the domain).

In order to prevent getting data from other domains, you should create a new Analytics view and [use a filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en) to include only traffic from your domain: Include only > traffic to the hostname > that contain and then add your domain in the input box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Reach out to them if you can and ask them to take it down.
2. Try to find out if you can take legal help to take it down look into DMCA notice.
3. Just so that you don't want to mess up your GA account till you get this sorted, create a 'view' filter with hostname. Add annotation to keep track if adding filter to same view.

[image]
OR you can use a hostname segment to remove it from your reports